# Intellij: Remote debugger is not stopping at breakpoint

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm having this interminent problem where remote debugging doesnt stop at breakpoint. To resolve this issue I have to rebuild my application again which take close to 15 min everytime. I have added below line in build.xml for remote connection.

Tried out clearing the cache and followed some of the approaches present in the stackoverflow but none seems to resolve my issue

Expected: Remote debugger should stop at breakpoint everytime 
Actual: Its not happening

Comment: Check the [debugger logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241125). Most likely, you are connecting to the JVM that either runs a different version of your classes or no such classes at all.

Comment: @CrazyCoder already tried it. It seems JVM is running same version of classes but intellij is not able to display the exact frame. This happening to me if if I'm debuggin the application more than 3-4 times

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the reproducible test case: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).